# How to pass parameters to an AWS Lambda Function using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have written an AWS Lambda function in Python that filters through instances and turns them on or off depending on how they are tagged. This will show you a working function, and the set-up needed to get it working. If you have questions on anything post it in the comments.

Here is my Lambda Function as of now:

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    startStop = event['startStop']
    vertical = event['vertical']
    isRunning = ''

    if(startStop == 'start'):
        isRunning = 'stopped'
    elif (startStop == 'stop'):
        isRunning = 'running'

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    filters = [
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': [isRunning] 
        },
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Vertical',
            'Values': [vertical]
        }
    ]

    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    runningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    if len(runningInstances) > 0:
        if(startStop == 'start'):
            shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=runningInstances).start()
        elif (startStop == 'stop'):
            shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=runningInstances).stop()
```

For reference, here is my mapping template:

```
{
    "startStop":"$input.params('startStop')",
    "vertical":"$input.params('vertical')"
}
```

And this is how I am passing in the parameters within the URL:

```
https://awslambdaapiurl.../prod/-params?startStop=start&vertical=TEST
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out the answer to my original question, so I have posted the working code as a resource for anyone to look at.

Comment: Can you just paste what you did as an answer and mark this as answered.

Comment: Sure, should I just delete the post and then re-post it as an answer? @AbhignaNagaraja

Comment: @DougAndres It's not necessary to repost. Just rollback the changes in the question as it was at the beginning (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45198321/1), and add what you did as an answer for this question. Then, mark it as answered and that's it! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Pass in parameter values in a mapping template:

```
{
    "startStop":"$input.params('startStop')",
    "vertical":"$input.params('vertical')"
}
```

Read parameter values via `event` Object:

```
    startStop = event['startStop']
    vertical = event['vertical']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **queryStringParameters** on **event** object.

```
request_data = event['queryStringParameters']
startStop = request_data['startStop']
vertical = request_data['vertical']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Asker answered their question by editing their post, but for other newbies:
When passing parameters via URL, the `event` parameter within the `lambda_handler` function is a dictionary where the URL parameters are within the `queryStringParameters` key:

Entering in your browser `https://awslambdaapiurl/?startStop=start&vertical=TEST`
would be accessed by python within the `lambda_handler` function as:

```
event['queryStringParameters']['startStop']
event['queryStringParameters']['vertical']
```

Comment: My answer is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64043328/4420657, just more wordy.
I am leaving my answer in addition since I feel the more verbose explanation was needed for my brain.